# Ease of use of OneNote on the Lumia 925

Tags: 8.0, lumia

I have been using Microsoft Office OneNote since I started working 3 years ago, and my only issue has been that I wish I had known about it when I was studying. I consider it a critical part of not just my working life, where I use it to take notes on projects, keep minutes etc, but also my personal life, where I keep general clippings from the internet, ideas and other things. It is the first thing I open when I get to work, and when I turn on my computer at home.

I have been holding onto my N8 until I could get a worthy replacement in the Nokia family. I feel that the Lumia 925 is that, and it has just been made available in my country. Using OneNote on my N8 is a pain; it's very slow, and wouldn't work at all until I flashed it with some custom firmware. Also the 3.5" screen is not that great for taking notes.

Before upgrading, my question is, is there any lag when taking notes in OneNote on the Lumia 925 (and by extension, WP8 in general)? Does the app make good use of the available 4.5" screen real estate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OneNote on Windows Phone is a very different application that its desktop version. It only has a subset of features, mostly text-based input. If you can get by with this set of features, there is no lag and it performs and syncs well. If you need to do more handwritten notes or image highlighting, or any other non - text feature it isn't available.

Comment: I understand that it is a more scaled down version, I am not expecting the same functionality. As long as it starts up quickly (better than the 2 odd minutes it takes to open on my N8) and there are no problems with syncing I'll be happy. Thanks

Comment: I have two notes in my Start Screen. They open and show theirs contents in less than 2 seconds. Add more 5 to 10 seconds to sync in a third country 3G and you are good to go. Try one in a store, you will see. Amazing fast.

Comment: I would love to try one in a store, but of my local mall's 3 cellullar shops, none of them have one on display. It's been like that for a while now, there will be posters for Nokia but they bring one from the back for you to view, Samsung phones are on all the stands, with Sony and HTC sometimes. And when you ask to see the Nokia (any Nokia), the guy will try to convince you to take a S4.

Comment: Without knowing where you are several stores I have been to carry Windows Phones in stock, but not displayed. Sometimes you have to ask to see one.

Answer (score 0):

I use OneNote occasionally on my Lumia 620. The startup time is about 3 seconds, and after that it runs completely smooth. There should be even less lag using the Lumia 925.

Comment: That sounds awesome, especially for when I am at a colleague's desk and we figure something out which I would like to Note immediately.